# Need logic in my index.html to render information from services

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I'm developing a web app using Angular 7.1. I have no pre-experience with that framework.
The project does already have a localization (two languages). I want to add meta tags in my `<head>` and also a fitting html lang attribute. But all the logic and all the components start at `<app-root></app-root>`. There is no .js or .ts file for index.html. I don't know how I could access my `translateService` to get the current language.

Of course I googled on the problem. But no solution did work or could be implemented in my project. It is like they were using old versions of Angular that had a whole other structure. Sometimes they would provide JS code and no word about where it is supposed to be.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My app</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The index.html is in the root directory of my application.

Comment: have you asked your teammates?

Comment: @Aprillion Yes, they also have too little experience with Angular

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly, you have not actually linked the Angular Framework nor any other external Javascript file in your HTML file.

So, therefore, your tag `<app-root></app-root>` will not work.

Aside from that, I think you need to provide more information about your problem since I don't see `translateService` anywhere in the code you say you are trying to access.

Comment: It does work! I don't know why or how, but I can start my application normally with `ng serve` and in the html response some scripts are inserted at the end of the `<body>`.
There is no place to use translateService. In other components I'm declaring `private translateService: TranslateService` and thus can use it with `this.translateService.currentLang`. But how am I supposed to do it in the index.html?